# HTML-I'm trying to centre an input slider while keeping the text around it normal

Tags: html, css, input, slider

I'm a new user on this platform and English is not my main language so excuse my mistakes. I'll start by first attaching the code.

[HTML code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuLf1.png)

[CSS code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjfoe.png)

```css
.container_beta
{
  text-align: center;
}
.container_beta input
{
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_beta">
          <span>Easy</span>
          <input type="range" name="difficulty" id="difficulty" min="0" max="5" step="1">
          <span>Hard</span>
      </div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to center the input while keeping the words to the right and the left as close as possible to the slider. Problem is that with this code , if I change the length of the words , the center is moved , which I don't want. I want to keep the center as it is, while being able to change the words.
So my question for today is what changes do I make to the code so that it behaves as I want ?

Comment: do you want to center the words vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flex makes this easier. Use flex instead of text-center to center main contents and add an additional wrapper around the input and labels to centre its content with flex too.

I added a red background so you can easily see its all centred as expected

```css
.container_beta {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}
.container_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container_beta input {
  width:500px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_beta">
    <div class="container_inner">
        <span>Easy</span> <input id="difficulty" max="5" min="0" name="difficulty" step="1" type="range"> <span>Hard</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternative solution

```css
.container_beta {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px
}
.labels {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container_beta input {
  width:500px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_beta">
  <div>
    <div class="labels">
      <span>Easier Label</span>
      <span>Hard</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container_inner">
        <input id="difficulty" max="5" min="0" name="difficulty" step="1" type="range"> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Sadly , I applied your code and it still moves the slider when I change the length of the word. If I change the word "Easy" to a longer one like  "Eeaassyy" the slider will move to the right . What I want is to keep the position of the slider in the center.

Comment: In your example the text is off the vertical center which is what I assumed you wanted fixed. You are talking about horizontal center.. increasing the length of the label will push the slider to the right because of the natural flow of HTML - by adding more text you are increasing width.I don't see how you can achieve this realistically. You could make the left & right label fixed widths & position so the slider won't move but then longer text will just move on top/over of the slider. Your best bet is to put the labels above the slider on the left and right so the slider is always full width.

Comment: I posted an alternative solution. This is how I have handled this before when I ran into the same issue.

Comment: Thank you soo much ! This actually looks much better and makes more sense . Thanks for the solution . Have a great day !